# Spark schema for Struct field containing array of struct

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to land the data on HDFS by reading the employee table schema.

```
create external table employee(
emp_id string,
emp_details struct<fname:string,lname:string,other_details:array<struct<other_details_code:string>>>
)
```

I am getting compilation error while creating schema for the above table.

```
val empSchema = StructType(StructField("emp_id", StringType) ::
StructField("emp_details", StructType(Array(StructField("fname", StringType),StructField("lname", StringType), ArrayType(StructType(Array(StructField(other_details_code, StringType))))
)) ::
Nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val empSchema = StructType(
    StructField("emp_id", StringType) ::
    StructField("emp_details", 
        StructType(Array(
            StructField("fname", StringType),
            StructField("lname", StringType), 
            StructField("other_details", ArrayType(StructType(Array(StructField("other_details_code", StringType)))))
        ))
    ) ::
Nil)
```

Note that the array of struct should be wrapped inside a `StructField` `other_details`.